# Backing up the SQL Application

Tags: sql-server, backup

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server that needs to be periodically reset to a clean state. Normally I would look at creating an image of the system drive, however due to organizational reasons I cannot use an image for this purpose.

So what I'm working on is using a combination of Windows System Restore and SQL's internal backup. The piece I'm missing right now is how to actually back up the SQL 2008 R2 Instance and associated configuration settings.

Basically I would like to be able to save a snapshot of the instance itself (logins, schemas, defaults, etc.) as well as anything necessary to restore the application to a working state from a bare metal restore (so things like service owners and registry keys).

Does SQL itself have a way to do this or do I have to look for another way to back up the application? For the logins, schemas and defaults, are those contained within one of the system databases?

Comment: Using a combination of a Restore Point and a Volume Shadow Copy sounds reasonable to me... I've never attempted anything like that, though. An O/S image really is the way to go.

Comment: I don't think I can do a Volume Shadow Copy of the system drive (which is where the OS and SQL live, but not the databases). I might have to yell at people to let me just do an image of that drive.

Comment: I believe you can Shadow Copy just a folder, not the entire volume (I was thinking all the SQL files would be on a volume separate from the system volume).

Comment: You just blew my mind. I'll check that out.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I was wrong. I just played with this. The volume snapshot gets enabled at the volume level, and then you can restore anything on that volume individually. You're right, though, that I can't seem to restore on a system volume. If you can move SQL off there (it's a good idea anyway), this solution should work.

Comment: I've gotta tear down this server eventually and rebuild it. I'm going to consider moving SQL onto its own dedicated logical drive at that point, so we'll see. For now, you can restore individual folders it just looks like you've gotta copy/paste instead of any sort of more automated thing.

Comment: Yeah, I recommend moving SQL off the system volume as a best practice anyway. For automation, a quick Google search turned up this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adioltean/archive/2004/12/30/344476.aspx

Comment: @Sean i might be getting the wrong end of the stick here  . . . when we engage in DR testing, we must the ensure two environments (live/DR) are consistent, effectively _backing up_ the instance. On live we backup databases (or mirror or log ship), script out jobs and logins en masse to allow for restore on another (DR)instance. Robocopy to copy application specific config that would need to exist if the database was running elsewhere. Though simple, maybe something like that might satisfy the requirement to backup an instance.